# Array.Reverse() versus Enumerable.Reverse<TSource>()

Tags: .net, linq

I have a single dimensional array of items declared and initialized as:

```
string[] SubDirectorylist = Directory.GetDirectories(TargetDirectory);
```

I'd like to reverse the members and found [`Enumerable.Reverse<TSource>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx).

What advantages, if any, does LINQ's implementation of reverse have over [`Array.Reverse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932.aspx)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`System.Linq.Enumerable.Reverse()` works on all classes that implement `IEnumerable` where as `System.Array.Reverse()` only works on arrays. If you know that you have an array, there is nothing wrong with using `System.Array.Reverse()`.

Comment: Not only is there nothing wrong with it, but it probably has better performance...

Comment: @Thomas: If the result should be an array instead of an `IEnumerable`: agreed.

Answer (score 14):

Beside what Daniel told `System.Linq.Enumerable.Reverse()` actually creates a copy then iterates it from end to beginning, when `System.Array.Reverse()` does in place transformation.

Comment: Remarks on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx): "This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action..." "This sorting method does not consider the actual values themselves in determining the order. Rather, it just returns the elements in the reverse order from which they are produced by the underlying source."  A convoluted way of saying what you've commented on, I think... :)  Thanks!

Comment: @mbrownnyc well, MSDN doesn't explicitly states that `IEnumerable.Reverse` creates a copy, because it is not strictly necessary for arrays. I found it out by decompiling the assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

If Performance matters to you, use `Array.Reverse()`.
`System.Linq.Enumerable.Reverse()` has the advantage of working on every IEnumerable like Arrays, Lists and so on.